# Can we update auto Product Attribute On Base of Stock Status In Admin Product Magento 2.4?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, product-attribute, magento2.4, stock-status

I want to update automatically Product Attribute on Base of Stock status in Product, I have created few attributes with `Yes/NO`. Now I want when the product will become out of stock that attribute will update automatically `NO`.

If Product is

`In-stock` = Product Attribute is `Yes`

`Out-of-stock` = Product Attribute is `No`

Can we do this?

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Using the event: **cataloginventory_stock_item_save_after**
You can create your own observer where you can check if the stock_status changed to "out of stock" and set your attributes accordingly (All of this if you added the attribute's inside the Magento stock table)

```
public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
{
    $stockItem = $observer->getEvent()->getItem();
    $origStockStatus = $stockItem->getOrigData('is_in_stock');
    $newStockStatus = $stockItem->getData('is_in_stock');
    if(($origStockStatus != $newStockStatus) && $newStockStatus === 0){
         $stockItem->setData('custom_stock_attribute', 0);
         $stockItem->save();
    }

}
```

That's only if your attribute is a stock attribute, if that's a product attribute then you can still use this observer but you'll have to load the product from the stock item:

```
$_productId = $stockItem->getProductId();  // you will get product ID 
$_product = $this->productRepository->getById($productId)
$_product->setData('custom_stock_attribute',0);
$_product->save();
```

Or you can also save only the attribute, if you fear an infinite loop

```
$product->setData('custom_stock_attribute', $custom_stock_attribute);
$product->getResource()->saveAttribute($product, 'custom_stock_attribute');
```

Comment: This is a very bad suggestion. Saving the stock item in an after event will cause an infinite loop.

Comment: i've edited the answer